# W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for *key* found on class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I was trying to load a single User's profile into an object, the thing is the program does get the wished key of the Reference I have but the error happens when the app gets the Profile object and all his getters return null.

Here is what my log prints:

```
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -K2Hh5c8ltlwIXNO44Rp found on class 
com.example.android.firetest.models.Profiles
I/System.out: the user's id: null
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.firetest, PID: 8546
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method'
java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference 
at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:263)
                  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
                  at com.example.android.firetest.Account_balance$2.onDataChange(Account_balance.java:263)
```

my method to retrive the user data :

```
private void loadUserdata() {
    System.out.println("entro aqui !");
    Query profileQuery = myRef.child("profiles").orderByChild("email").equalTo("jose.nieto@riagency.us").limitToFirst(1);
    profileQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Profiles user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Profiles.class);
            System.out.println("the user's id: "+user.getId());
            base_salary = user.getBase_salary();
            cedula = user.getId();
            //Here is where the error happens
            Double monto_quincenal = Double.parseDouble(base_salary)/2;
            primera_quincena.setText(monto_quincenal.toString());
            segunda_quincena.setText(monto_quincenal.toString());
            Account_name.setText(user.getFirst_name() +" "+ user.getLast_name());
            refOrder = myRef.child("invoices").child(year.getSelectedItem().toString())
                    .child(month.getSelectedItem().toString())
                    .orderByChild("id").equalTo(cedula);
            System.out.println("la cedula en el metodo "+cedula);

                    populateInvoiceList();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("the has been an error retrieving the user data: \n" + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

I don't really know why it says that base_salary is null when it was already assigned below

The POJO:

```
public class Profiles {
private String age;
private String email;
private String name;
private String image;
private String first_name;
private String address;
private String avatar;
private String base_salary;
private String birthday_date;
private String city;
private String counrty_code;
private String dpto;
private String id;
private Boolean is_leader;
private String last_name;
private String occupation;
private String phone;
private int registered_at;
private String role;
private Boolean status;
private int updated_at;

public Profiles() {
}

public Profiles(String age, String email, String name, String first_name,
                String image, String address, String avatar, String base_salary, String counrty_code, String birthday_date,
                String city, String dpto, String id, Boolean is_leader, String occupation, String last_name,
                String phone, int registered_at, String role, Boolean status, int updated_at) {
//**
}
```

the Firebase reference:

```
firetest-e5a93/profiles/-K2Hh5c8ltlwIXNO44Rp
-K2Hh5c8ltlwIXNO44Rp
address: "cra 45, calle 75b sur, int 106, edif las acasia..."
avatar: "avatar.jpg"
base_salary: "300000"
birthday_date: "1986-01-03"
city: "sabaneta"
counrty_code: "CO"
dpto: 2
email: "jose.nieto@riagency.us"
first_name: "Jose Gabriel"
has_avatar: true
id: "060514699"
interests: "PHP, Js, html, css, AngularJS, laravel, cakephp..."
is_leader: true
last_name: "Nieto Avila"
occupation: "Ing en Informatica"
phone: "3223349524"
position: "Lider Development"
registered_at: 1446643984181
role: "admin"
schedule_special: true
status: true
team_name: "Fino Code"
updated_at: 1446643984181
```

as you can see, in the Log we got the same **Key** but the Profile object seems to be null, any ideas?

Comment: Edited my answer, missed the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an age property in your POJO that's not in your firebase reference and a team_name in your firebase reference that's not in your POJO.

### Edit

Oh and also, that query will return an array of Profiles, rather than a Profile. Which is why it's trying to set that key as a property. Try getting the first child of the snapshot.

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    Profiles profile = snapshot.getValue(Profiles.class);
    System.out.println(profile);
}
```

Comment: POJO updated, how can I turn that array into a single profile?

Comment: well my code gets further but it stops declaring the Object.     **Edit**   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.android.firetest, PID: 2071
                  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Numeric       value out of 32-bit integer range: 1.446643984181E12. Did you mean to use a long or double instead of an int?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, add the error to your question.

Comment: That's because your updated_at is too long to fit in an int, chance it to a Double or Long. Same with registered_at

Comment: Faced the same issue and wasted 10 mins. Learning --> "Snapshot is always a list."